# Android Studio "Error while Running application" Compile is Obsolete

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have old android studio project when i updated the android studio and import that project its give me this error I have updated the gradle file but it always give me this error.

Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api' [duplicate]

I have change all compile to implementation but its always give me this error. Please Help me to resolve this issue .
here is the code....

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ask4task.easygroc"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.6.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.3.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
implementation 'me.henrytao:smooth-app-bar-layout:24.1.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.xiaofeng.android:flowlayoutmanager:1.2.3.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
//compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.0'
        }
    }
}
 }
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Did you ran the gradle sync command after changing to implementation?

Comment: I guess it can be the libraries that use compile instead on implementation. Or this is warning for everyone. Got the same warning

Comment: yes. thats run perfect but when i run the app this error accurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Gradle version to 4.4 with Android Gradle Plugin to 3.1.4

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

**build.gradle (Top-level)**

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
```

Comment: Thank you Soo much this helps me and resolve my problem